# Error setting CRON job for Amazon server

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I created a simple method just t show "Hellp World" in cron job.

I ran **php index.php tools message**

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx:/var/www/html$ php index.php tools message
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in /var/www/html/application/config/constants.php on line 176
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined index: REMOTE_ADDR</p>
<p>Filename: core/Input.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 351</p>

</div><div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/html/system/core/Exceptions.php:185)</p>
<p>Filename: libraries/Session.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 688</p>
```

This is what I am getting.In my constant page I have defined a variable

```
define('RELATIVE_PATH','http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/');
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818129/why-am-i-getting-undefined-index-http-host-error)

Answer (score 0):

Undefined index is not possible in your code. `HTTP_HOST` is not set if you run php in command line, because this `HTTP_HOST` is set by web server.

Like its written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818129/why-am-i-getting-undefined-index-http-host-error) that if you run PHP from a cron, it runs like CGI, many environment variables are not set by the server. In that case there is no web server and no `HTTP_HOST`.

Despite of that, Web browser sets `HOST header` to the request to the web server, so if we run from a web-browser there is an HTTP environment exists. I found a work around in this case-

Pass Hostname as a parameter to the CLI

> ```
> $php -f mycronjob.php HOST=www.mywebsite.com #example website
> ```

mycronjob.php

```
<?php
$host = $_GET['HOST']; // Get the host via GET params
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.If I omit that still other issues are showing.Can you help with that?

Comment: 1.Undefined index: REMOTE_ADDR
2.Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by