# Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, centos7

i get in error log :

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in
>   /var/www/html/web/libraries/src/Application/WebApplication.php on line
>   988

and code in this line : `$uri = $scheme . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_HOST in
>   /var/www/html/web/libraries/src/Uri/Uri.php on line 90

and code in this line : `$theURI = 'http' . $https . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Seems like you are doing something CLI:- [Why am i getting Undefined index: HTTP_HOST error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818129/why-am-i-getting-undefined-index-http-host-error)  And [CodeIgniter Forums](https://forum.codeigniter.com/archive/index.php?thread-43743.html)

Comment: I think it doesn't work for me. I have tried it before.

Comment: @CintaDewiAmelia add complete code in respective error throwing  Lines in `/src/Uri/Uri.php` and `src/Application/WebApplication.php`

Comment: How is `$config['basepath']` defined in your config? If you run Codeigniter in CLI mode, you can't deal with `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and should define it per environment then.

Comment: i can't find $config['basepath'] in my config file, should i add it?

Comment: I think @moveax meant to say `$config['base_url'];`

Comment: Yeah, sry `$config['base_url']` is the proper naming

Comment: i have customize my $config['base_url'] with should. possible errors in settings php other?

Comment: Are you running the Script from the CLI or not? Please show us the content of the named config variable, otherwise we wouldnt be able to help at all

Comment: thank you all, i think i have found the solution

Comment: What was the solution please. I have the same problem. CLI cron job giving this error having moved from Codeigniter 2 to Codeigniter 3.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe help you

```php
$server_name = !empty($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] : 'localhost:8080';
$base = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $server_name . '/';
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. That would also give a more assertive impression than "Maybe ...".